# html and javascript form not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

THis is the code :

```
<script>
    function searchFor(searchEngine,searchQuery){
        if (searchEngine="google"){
            var x="http://google.com.hk/search?q="+searchQuery;
            window.location=x
        }

        if (searchEngine="yahoo"){
            var x="http://hk.search.yahoo.com/search?p="+searchQuery;
            window.location=x
        }
     }
</script>

<form>
     <input type="radio" name="searchLoc" value="google"> Google <input type="radio" name="searchLoc" value="yahoo"> Yahoo
     <br>
     <input type="text" name="searchContent">
     <input type="submit" onclick="searchFor(this.form.searchLoc.value,this.form.searchContent.value);return false;" value="Search"
</form>
```

Why is it not working?

Once i click the submit button, nothing happened.

Pls help. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain error

a) it should be window.location.href

b) close the submit button tag

c) use '==' equal to for comparision

```
  <script>
    function searchFor(searchEngine,searchQuery){

     for (var i = 0; i < searchEngine.length; i++) {
        if (searchEngine[i].type === 'radio' && searchEngine[i].checked) {

            value = searchEngine[i].value;       
        }
    }


        if (value=="google"){
        var x="http://google.com.hk/search?q="+searchQuery;
        window.location.href=x
        }
        if (value=="yahoo"){
        var x="http://hk.search.yahoo.com/search?p="+searchQuery;
        window.location.href=x
        }
    }
    </script>

    <form>
    <input type="radio" name="searchLoc" value="google"> Google <input type="radio" name="searchLoc" value="yahoo"> Yahoo
    <br><input type="text" name="searchContent">
    <input type="submit" onclick="searchFor(this.form.searchLoc,this.form.searchContent.value);return false;" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write

```
<script>
function searchFor(searchEngine,searchQuery){
if (searchEngine=="google"){
var x="http://google.com.hk/search?q="+searchQuery;
window.location=x
}
if (searchEngine=="yahoo"){
var x="http://hk.search.yahoo.com/search?p="+searchQuery;
window.location=x
}
}
</script>
```

'==' instead of '=' in comparison

Change submit button also,

```
<input type="submit" onclick="searchFor(this.form.searchLoc.value,this.form.searchContent.value);return false;" value="Search" />
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
  if (searchEngine="google")
```

try this:

```
if (searchEngine === "google")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function searchFor(searchEngine,searchQuery){
    if (searchEngine=="google"){
        var x="http://google.com.hk/search?q="+searchQuery;
        window.location=x
    }
    if (searchEngine=="yahoo"){
        var x="http://hk.search.yahoo.com/search?p="+searchQuery;
        window.location=x;
    }
}
</script>

<form onsubmit="searchFor(this.form.searchLoc.value,this.form.searchContent.value);return false;">
<input type="radio" name="searchLoc" value="google"> Google <input type="radio" name="searchLoc" value="yahoo"> Yahoo
<br><input type="text" name="searchContent">
<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

Modify the code as above. searchEngine="google" should be searchEngine == "google" and use onsubmit on  tag instead of onclick on submit button.